# Create a custom DateTimePicker in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

In a sheet I have a column to enter a datetime value that would later be checked by a script to create a trigger.
I would like to set a picker in that column to ease selection and avoid errors.

I know Google Sheets offers an option in Data Validation for date but not for time neither datetime.

However, I found this class in the Google Apps Script API

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/date-time-picker

But I just do not know how to implement it in a sheet (e.g. with OnEdit() or SetDataValidation()) so any time I press enter any cell in that column the picker is called to select datetime and set cell value to that selection.

Answer (score 0):

The referred class belongs to the Card Service which is only available for G Suite add-ons.

To build a custom date picker for Google Sheets you could use the HTML Service. For further details see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html